Conservation of angular momentum of disc during rolling onto step
If a ball rolls without slipping and then hits a single step with height lower than it's radius and rolls on without any slipping about the step edge as the axis of rotation onto the step then can we conserve angular momentum about the step edge axis?
Considering that the gravitational force acting on the center of mass of the sphere as it rolls about the step edge axis would apply torque, would it not be incorrect to find the final velocity on the step by conserving angular momentum about the step edge axis? And it would be better to solve by conserving energy and accounting for the gain in gravitational potential energy and equating both linear and rotational kinetic energies in the initial and final(on step) stage assuming pure rolling to find final velocity? The arrow in the image points to what I refer as the step edge axis of rotation.

This confusion arrived mainly as the solution from this book shows the answer as 5/6 of original velocity of center of mass however problem 264 from IE Irodov's problems in general physics: http://irodovsolutionsmechanics.blogspot.com/2008/12/irodov-problem-1264.html
approaches a similar question with the energy conservation solution, so which method am I supposed to use?
